# Full list of ways to declare variables, types, and alike in ABAP

Tags: abap

I try to compile all ways that ABAP provides to declare variables, types, and alike, including obsolete and acrane syntax variants. So, for example, I would include FIELD-GROUPS in the list but not the declaration of classes.  My current list is as follows.  Did I miss anything?

- statements declaring variables

  - DATA-like declarative statements

    DATA (excluding DATA BEGIN OF COMMON PART), STATICS, PARAMETER, PARAMETERS, CONSTANTS
  - FIELD-SYMBOLS
  - inline declarations
  - actual parameters of procedures

    FORM (subroutine), FUNCTION, METHOD
  - other variable declaring statements

    RANGES, SELECT-OPTIONS: Are there further?
- statements declaring types

  - TYPES
- other statements

  - DATA BEGIN OF COMMON PART

    not a declarative statement in itself but a way to group further DATA statements.
  - FIELD-GROUPS

    declares an extract dataset, which is not part of the ABAP type concept for data types and data objects

Disclaimer: We are writing a tool in Java that parses and transforms ABAP code. In particular, we have no intention to write new ABAP code. But instead, our tool has to handle all of ABAP, even obsolete statements and obscure syntax variants. Furthermore, I'd like to mention that I'm not an ABAP expert.

Comment: You might want to check out the syntax definitions maintained in ABAPlint. They are sometimes more complete than the documentation and are maintained in machine-readable format. https://syntax.abaplint.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete your list, you may add these ones (partially taken from the [ABAP doc - obsolete declarations](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenobsolete_declarations.htm)) :

- `TABLES`
- `NODES`
- `LOCAL`
- `FIELDS`
- `CLASS-DATA`
- `ALIASES` for attributes (not really a declaration, but it adds a new name for the given attributes)
- `CONTROLS`

There are the **auxiliary variables** inside constructor expressions (FOR aux..., FOR , LET ...)

Programs have **predefined** types and variables (`SY`, `SCREEN` and so on; I feel you can extract all of them from the "implicit system includes" but you must know those includes).

Eventually consider the statements inside **macros**, either internal (`DEFINE`) or external (table `TRMAC`).

There are statements which correspond to **internal includes**:

- `TYPE-POOLS` (was mandatory before 7.02)
- `INFOTYPES`
- `CONTEXTS`

Of course, there are also all the **DDIC types**.

I don't know if you want to scan also `CREATE DATA` (for tools like abstract interpreters).

PS: you say that common parts are not real declarative statements, that's wrong, they declare data objects, plus an additional "sharing feature".

Comment: Thanks! Regarding COMMON PART: I wrote "not a declarative statement" because their contained elements look like regular DATA declarations and, w.r.t. the list, I consider them to be coverd by the first point.

Comment: + `CONTROLS` (declares screen variables for table controls and table strips)